# angular 5 if statment for value

Tags: angular, angular5

my varible may contains 3 value , passed/rejected/unknown

im tying to show `unknow` when value is unknown and show `passed` when value is passed and `rejected` wjen value is rejected .
by this code it not working when value is unknown how should fix this?

```
  <td>
        <div *ngIf="s.resume_qualify === 'UNKNOWN';then content else other_content">unknown</div>

              <ng-template #content *ngIf="s.resume_qualify === 'PASSED'">passwd</ng-template>
              <ng-template #other_content *ngIf="s.resume_qualify === 'REJECTED'">rejected</ng-template>
     </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the [**NgSwitch**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) which is more preferable in this case.

```
<div [ngSwitch]="s.resume_qualify">
  <ng-template *ngSwitchCase="'UNKNOWN'">unknown</ng-template>
  <ng-template *ngSwitchCase="'PASSED'">passed</ng-template> 
  <ng-template *ngSwitchCase="'REJECTED'">rejected</ng-template>
</div>
```

Check [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnguk2)

Answer (score 0):

Well, given your example there, you can simplify your code :

```
<p>{{ s.resume_qualify | lowercase }}</p>
```

If it doesn't suit you, please provide your error or some mode code.